# Show Android Webview with transparent background

Tags: android, background, webview, transparent

i would like to load an animated gif. I found out that i could load it in a WebView. Now i have created a class extending from WebView. It looks like this:

```
public class GifWebView extends WebView {

public GifWebView(Context context, String path) {
  super(context);

  loadUrl(path);

  setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

  }
}
```

Unfortunately the background is black. Do you know a solution? I tried it on Android 4.1.2. I have already searched on stackoverflow but I did not find a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Its a issue with Android https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14749

Comment: By the way did you try setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); ?

Comment: You are right. Because of this issue i used the movies class instead of WebView. I had to set the background of the Activity. That solved my problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the background of the document you are providing. Since webview loads the document above its background

Comment: I am loading an Image. How should i change it? It is an gif image with transparent background. By the way: Color.GREEN works fine.